# git переключение между ключами

Tags: git

2 акк. на гитхаб, к каждому создал SHH ключи (1th_rsa, 2th_rsa). Как между ними переключаться в консоли, что бы работать с разными удалёнными репо?

Comment: если ты про "git config user.name/email"  - не переключает. "ssh -T git@github.com" высвечивает "old_user", если я нахожусь директории "new_user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в файле `~/.ssh/config` создать записи для двух аккаунтов github

```
Host github.com-acc1
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_acc1

Host github.com-acc2
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_acc1
```

Тогда при клонировании для использования определенного ключа нужно изменять домен github.com на требуемый

```
git clone git@github.com-acc1:git/git.git
git clone git@github.com-acc2:git/git.git
```

Взято [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996/e873a4931584eacda354b1313a8c19dda6bc630f)

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии `2.3.0` можно указать переменную окружения [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) таким образом:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foobar"
```

При последующих командах `git` будет использовать указанный SSH-ключ.

Comment: Неудобно, что нужно постоянно переключать.